# how to grep "Use%" value when df

Tags: linux

When I use `df` command in Linux, I get the info. like:

[image: [enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3koN.png)

I want to get "20%" in the last row using df command with regular expression, what should I do ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the actual result you're trying to get? It would make the question a bit clearer, and will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df|tail -1|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f5
```

**UPD** without `%` sign:

```
df|tail -1|tr -s ' '|cut -d ' ' -f5|tr -d '%'
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps!

Comment: u're welcome, u can upvote and accept answer. ^____^

Comment: BTW, if I want to remove % from 20%, what modifications shoud I do according to your command? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
df | awk 'END {print $5}'
```

`awk` process each line `df` outputs, when reaches the `END`, print the 5th field.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need grep or cut. Use the --output option like so `df --output=pcent`.
If you want the last row, use `df --output=pcent | tail -1` or maybe you could execute `df /data --output=pcent`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df /data | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

This will make `df` only consider the partition you're interested in, and then `awk` will extract the wanted column from the `df` output.

Note that instead of `/data` you may also use any subdirectory under `/data` that lives on the same partition.

Answer (score 0):

1. df will give you the output you want
2. then you can use awk to get the column you want $5 is for 5th column
3. At last grep the needed output

Code:

```
df -h | awk '{print $5}'
26%
26%
0%
0%
0%
0%
1%

df -h | awk '{print $5}'|grep "20%" will be needed in your case
```